# Scraping certain elements from HTML with BeautifulSoup, Python 3.3.2

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping data from a website that holds data in tables uniformly across multiple webpages, webpages such as this one:

https://www.topsport.com.au/Racing/Thoroughbreds/Kalgoorlie/R3/3975255

I'm scraping data from the #, Runner and Flucs columns using BeautifulSoup so i can organise them as I see fit. I'm successful in scraping them but I have no use for the horses that are scratched. When I scrap data from the fields these horses show up. You should note that the scratched horses are contained within a tr class tag labelled scratched and the horses that aren't are in tr classes that are unnamed.

HTML from the webpage that shows the different classes

```
<tr>...</tr> #classes that I want elements from
<tr class="scratched">...</tr> #classes I don't want elements from
```

This is the code that I use to collect the data from the webpage to be prepped for use.

```
ccnum = {'class' : 'competitorNumColumn'}
name = {'class' : 'rnnrName'}

saddC = soup.findAll(attrs = ccnum)
run = soup.findAll(attrs = name)
```

competitorNumColumn and rnnrName come up in both classes and are the identifiers for the elements that I want.

**The Issue:**
What exception can I add to the Python code so that all the elements will be scraped except those that are contained within a tr.scratched container?

Comment: `[tr.find_all(attrs=name) for tr in soup.find_all('tr', class_=lambda s:s != 'scratched')]` or you can use `re.compile` if you prefer.

Comment: Thank you! This leaves the scratched horses as a blank element in the list when printed which will be easy to discard once they need to be. Much appreciated!

Comment: You're very welcome @Toothpickss